# Type-safe `read` in Haskell

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) discusses the following data type:

```
data Day = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday   
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Bounded, Enum)
```

The book demonstrates how to use `read` to parse a String into a `Day` type.

```
$ read "Saturday" :: Day
Saturday
```

However, I can pass in a non-Day value, resulting in an exception.

```
$ read "foo" :: Day
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

What's a type-safe way to use `read` in the above example?

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the old standard function `reads` mentioned by @JonPurdy, there's also the more recently added

```
Text.Read.readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
```

which is simpler to use when the string contains just one value to parse.

Comment: That's certainly a useful function. I suppose using `Maybe` or `Either` (I think that's the type Jon proposed in his answer) is a matter of taste?

Comment: @KevinMeredith `Either` is essentially `Maybe` extended with the feature of more refined failure values. I note `readEither` just gives as a `Left` value the same error message as `read` would error out with, which you can then e.g. print if you want.

Comment: Also to make it clear, the main additional feature of `reads` is that it can parse just the beginning of the string, returning also the remaining string if you want to parse that further.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `reads`, which gives you a list of pairs of parsed values and unparsed remainders:

```
reads :: Read a => ReadS a
type ReadS a = String -> [(a, String)]
```

Now you can explicitly match on the result and do whatever you like:

```
case reads x of

  -- foo
  [] -> Left "no parse"

  -- Saturday
  [(day, "")] -> Right (day :: Day)

  -- Fridayum
  [(_, junk)] -> Left $ "day followed by extra junk: " ++ junk

  _ -> Left "ambiguous parse"
```

Though honestly I would estimate that exceptions have lower cost in GHC’s runtime…

For more complex things, you could write a parser using (for example) Parsec:

```
day :: Parser Day
day = choice
  [ Monday <$ string "Monday"
  , ...
  ] <* eof
```

And whichever parsing library you choose will have a means, such as Parsec’s `parse`, of running a parser and dealing with parse errors.

Comment: aside -I'd argue for correctness first rather than focus on performance. Is there a reason why you're focusing on performance, Jon?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: No particular reason, I just prefer not to pessimise. The documentation for `ReadS` says: “Note that this kind of backtracking parser is very inefficient; reading a large structure may be quite slow.”

Comment: could you please say a bit more as to your `case reads x` example? Simply, here's how I used your answer: `> `reads "foo" :: [(Day, String)]` returns `[]`. But I'm not sure how to use your `case reads ...` example. I'm guessing it's the same as Scala's `Either` type, but want to make sure.Thanks

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Yeah, I was just giving an example of the kinds of error handling you might like to do, by matching on that `[(Day, String)]` and returning `Either String Day`—either an error message (`Left`) or the result of a successful parse (`Right`).