# How to read/parse Int from String

Tags: haskell

I use `read "123" :: Int` to read in Int from String. This works great for a simple case such as `"123"`; But it fails when the input is `"12.34"`.

What do people usually do in such cases?

Edit: I also would like to know if there is a simple way to parse numbers with thousand separator such as `"12,345"`

Comment: `12.34` is not an `Int`. You can parse it to a `Float`, or a `Decimal`.

Comment: I feel like a lot of people answered without even knowing what the question was. What result do you *want* when given the input `"12.34"`? 12? 1234? Program dies? An error that you can dispatch on but doesn't kill the program? A split of the string into `"12"` and `".34"`? ...something else?

Comment: What about "12,343" with a thousand seperator?

Comment: What if I told you that in some parts of the world, the `.` in `12.345` is *also* a thousands separator? So I ask again: what result do you *want* when given the input `"12.345"`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My question is how to parse Int when given a string containing separators. Anyway, I see that I could simply use a filter to get rid of the separators. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Read a floating point number.

Consider reading a floating point number first, then rounding it as fits your application.

```
λ (round  . read) "12.34"   
12
```

Note that it can read a number without a dot as well:

```
λ (round  . read) "12"                  
12
```

### There are more rounding methods.

`Prelude` offers several functions for transforming fractions into integral numbers: beside the obvious `round`, there are `floor`, `ceiling` and `truncate`. [There are subtleties to them.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping)

### Rounding methods have polymorphic powers.

If you enable `-Wtype-defaults`, you will see that the number "12.34" is read as a `Double` and then transformed to `Integer`. If you inspect `round` though, you will see that it is quite general:

```
λ :type round
round :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

So, for instance, you may retrieve an `Int`.

```
λ (round  . read) "12.34" :: Int
12
```

### You can give type arguments to your functions.

You can use the `TypeApplications` language extension to get concise and flexible code. For instance, if you wish to parse an exotic looking `Rational` to a `Word8`:

```
λ round @_ @Word8 . read @Rational $ "2833 % 11"
2
```

### You can avoid run time errors.

You can get a run time error from any of the above, if someone supplies gibberish. One tiny typo is enough to bring the whole program down. And the [problem is remedied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23862038) already: we now have `readMaybe` in `Prelude`. See:

```
λ fmap round . readMaybe @Rational $ "339 % 108"
Just 3
λ fmap round . readMaybe @Rational $ "3.14159"
Nothing
```

I think `readMaybe` should be preferred to `read` whenever possible.

### Limitations of `instance Read` of basic number types.

The `Read` instances available in `Prelude` are geared towards the [lexical syntax of Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-190002.5), which means there is a single unified reading. It supports some notational conventions, like exponential notation, by default, optionally admits some more, like [binary literals](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-BinaryLiterals), and eschews others. For example, omitting `0` before the decimal separator is widely accepted in some countries, but it is not supported by any `Read` instance in `base`. The use of [thousands separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping), while it greatly facilitates the human understanding of large numbers, is, to my knowledge, also ignored. There is no effort whatsoever to support various regional standards and conventions in `base`, and, as far as I know, there is no *"go-to"* library to achieve more flexible support for parsing numbers at the moment.

So, if you require something *"unusual"* — that is, exceeding the Haskell standard — the advice is twofold:

- Use a parsing library to construct a specialized parser. There is [a parser combinator module in `base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html), along with a wide choice of advanced and modern parsing libraries on Hackage.
- Use a simple hack. For instance, if you wish to support thousands separators, you may do something like `filter (/= ',')`. Some [widely used tools](https://github.com/sol/doctest/blob/4da836a9b8bc2efbba5f27033c5a8fdc690e49b3/src/Parse.hs) in Haskell are built on hacks of this sort.

In the latter case, you should beware of possible ambiguity. For example, if you simply remove all non-number characters from the input string, you will cripple hexadecimals and exponential notation:

```
λ (round  . read) "2.6356e5"                  
263560
λ (round  . read . filter isNumber) "2.6356e5"
263565
```

I wish one day we will have stronger localization support. I think this comes with wide adoption, and Haskell is yet a local language.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. What about a number format with a thousand seperator such as "12,345" ?

Comment: @McBearHolden This is not optimistic. I updated my answer. In short, use `filter (/= ',')`.

Comment: Thanks. Adding a filter function is the simplest one.

Answer (score 6):

This does not work, since `12.34` is *not* an `Int`eger. You can parse this as a [**`Float`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Float) or a [**`Decimal`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal-0.5.1/docs/Data-Decimal.html#t:Decimal) for example:

```
Prelude> read "12.34" :: Float
12.34
```